# Can the spike protein created by the Covid mRNA vaccines be created independently of the human body, and is there a higher cost to that?

Tags: mrna, gene-therapy, covid, vaccine

How different in principle is using the bodies own mRNA to create the coronavirus spike protein differ from other methods of using genes to manufacture other drugs or proteins and is there a cost benefit to it?

Take the scheme for instance that uses genetically modified genes in goats to manufacture spider silk, as shown in this link - [The goats with spider genes and silk in their milk](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/av/science-environment-16554357) or [Yeast cells genetically modified to create morphine-like pain killer](https://www.theguardian.com/science/2015/aug/13/yeast-cells-genetically-modified-to-create-morphine-like-painkiller)

I understand that in the case of the Covid vaccines the human body's genes themselves are not modified, but it is the principle of using the body's own cells as a manufacturer of some desired protein that I'm inquiring about.

Even without any cost-cutting benefit does the way Covid mRNA vaccines work differ in principle from other gene based compound manufacture?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about a biological mechanism or process.

Comment: It is about a biological process which in this case uses the human body as the system of manufacturing. Whether a cost benefit is a secondary issue, but it clearly has to be a factor given the huge scale on which it is being applied.
Is the scale the only reason why Covid has enabled mRNA vaccines managed to go mainstream or is just fortuitous timing?
The scale and the economics matter.

Comment: I don't think you're looking at this the right way and taking far too literally the meaning of "manufacturing" in this sense. You're comparing a vaccine to mass production of bulk materials. The mRNA- or viral-based covid vaccines produce very little protein in comparison.

Comment: @BryanKrause I'm not acquainted with the science here, as you can see that I have only asked one question here previously.
The question can be broken into 2 parts. 1. Whether  the spike protein can be manufactured independently of the human body, 2. If it can, why the human body is being used to produce it and whether is a cost benefit to it.
I assume for the layman there is the implied assumption that the human body is the only place the spike protein can be synthesized, but seeing that is not the first time gene manipulation have been used to create compounds is what prompts the question.

Comment: This site should find a way to enable discourse regarding the rapidly growing and extremely relevant field of bioengineering. Currently there is no "home" for it on Stack Exchange.

Comment: Bryans comment suggests he doesn't understand that the mRNA vaccine is also bulk manufactured. Bryan also says that the mRNA vaccine results in "very little protein" without citation, v questionable assertion.

Comment: (mRNA, protein) manufacture is an entire biology discipline relevant for medical and non medical industry. OPs question is a good one - is it easier to manufacture the mRNA than the protein, and is that part of why the vaccine is an mRNA vaccine.

Comment: If this isn't allowed, why don't the mods auto move it to medicine to help new users? Or even _suggest_ moving it? Negative reinforcement only in the website rules? Way to crush discourse...

Comment: @Amanda — If you want to have a discussion about how the site works please use the [meta] site rather than antagonizing Bryan (who like all moderators is a volunteer). ——— However, I encourage you to first familiarize yourself with how this site is supposed to work by taking the [tour] and then carefully reading through the [help] starting with with [ask] and [answer] questions effectively. In particular, note that *`Not all questions can or should be answered here.`* Thanks!

Comment: @vfclists Come support the SynBio Stackexchange proposal? As soon as we hit 100 people with 200+ reputation, an interdisciplinary site will be launched where questions like these are clearly on-topic. https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/125068/synthetic-biology?referrer=MTFmYjRhNDUzOTZkYmY1NjU0ODE5ZjczMWY0Y2RiMDFlNTQyOWI1MWZkNzQyMzRhYjk2MWU0YzAyNjE3NjA0M930KtpvebSN1XkrLHnQGy7CghuJQAyr-Me9iSdHtWfZ0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you describe, creating the spike protein independently and delivering it, is exactly what is done by [subunit vaccines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subunit_vaccine), such as [the COVID-19 vaccine developed by Novavax](https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2020/health/novavax-covid-19-vaccine.html).

As already noted in @Amanda's answer, mRNA is great at amplifying a delivery, so you need a lot less to be delivered.

The manufacturing process for the vaccine itself is a lot more modular as well, since you can address a new target simply by adjusting the contents of the mRNA. It's not necessarily simpler overall, though, since there are different challenges related to nanoparticle encapsulation and delivery.

The stability is also not necessarily better than for a subunit vaccine: proteins are sensitive and unstable, but so is mRNA.  The degree of sensitivity for mRNA, however, is more predictable than for protein, since the mRNA itself is a much simpler and more regularly structured molecule.

Answer (score 6):

It is quite costly and difficult to manufacture and store proteins. It's very likely more efficient to have the human cells create as much protein as they can, from a relatively small amount of mRNA. Remember than one mRNA molecule can be translated into protein many many many times, so the manufacturers need to only make one mRNA molecule to get many protein molecules, whereas it would be more expensive to manufacture many protein molecules.

It's kind of a "give a man a fish, he eats for a day, teach a man to fish, he eats forever" situation. Better to give the body the instructions (mRNA) than the product, for cost effectiveness.